# Execute Django shell command as cron

Tags: python, django, cron, scheduled-tasks, django-shell

I'm try to Execute Django shell command as `cron`,
I have some queries and objects tasks to search and read and write using the models and queries of my django app.

How can I  execute this 1 or 2 times a day?

For example, how can I run these queries periodically:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from perfil.models import *

for user in usuarios:
        profiles = Perfil.objects.filter(user=user)
        create_task = Task.objects.create(user=user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Custom management commands for django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/).

As a basic example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from perfil.models import *

class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = 'What does this do? '

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for user in usuarios:
            profiles = Perfil.objects.filter(user=user)
            create_task = Task.objects.create(user=user)
```

On a side note, you should be more explicit about your import and not use `from perfil.models import *`.

From that, you can execute the command based on the file you saved it in.  If you saved the file in `yourapp/management/commands/dofunstuff.py` than you could execute it via `python manage.py dofunstuff`.

Comment: im using this import on Perfil Model